# Deleting item in JSON file does not function as expected

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a function in my script which deletes an item in a script. However, instead of deleting it from the json file, it somehow appends to it in a weird sense:

My function:

```
def delete_first_entry():
    with open("dictionary.json", 'r+') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        newdata = data.pop(0)
        file.truncate()
        json.dump(newdata, file)
```

Original json file:

```
[{"gyfedz": ["gyfedz.jpg", "A short story"]}, 
{"ig9u4z": ["ig9u4z.jpg", "She did her best ok?"]}]
```

What I wanted:

```
[{"ig9u4z": ["ig9u4z.jpg", "She did her best ok?"]}]
```

What I got:

```
[{"gyfedz": ["gyfedz.jpg", "A short story"]}, 
{"ig9u4z": ["ig9u4z.jpg", "She did her best ok?"]}]
{"gyfedz": ["gyfedz.jpg", "A short story"]}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?
(Side note: I would appreciate if there are better ways of writing this function. I am quite new to python and file management in general)

Comment: why not  simply do this ```data[1]```?

Comment: I tried using data[1:], unfortunately this still does not fix the problem

Comment: The code of @Ftoy do the work.
But one problem I see in your code is writing to an input file. If the file is importance, you may lose them forever if something wrong happen

Comment: Would be easier to open once for reading, close, then a second time for writing.

Answer (score 0):

This does work,

```py
def delete_first_entry():
    with open("dictionary.json", 'r+') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        print(data)
        newdata = data.pop(0)
        print(data)
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()
        json.dump(newdata, file)
```

After reading, your file pointer is at the end of the file so you want it to move back to the start of the file to truncate to my understanding.